# Can mouseenter and click event exist together?

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if mouseenter and click event can exist together and they can both exist to TRUE when checked with:

```
if ((evt.type === 'mouseenter') && (evt.type === 'click'))
```

It is because when I mouse over the link, the mouseenter triggers (set to TRUE) and even when I clicked on it, the hover is still shown. Probably they could exist together but I'm no expert on this.

If someone can give insights, I would appreciate it a lot.

Also how can I trigger the click event during the mouseenter event?

Comment: How is it possible to click and not hover? I don't get what you're trying to do. Can you post an example of what you want?

Comment: @elclanrs - Press tab to focus on a button, then press enter. Or on a mobile device, hover will not be fired.

Comment: Of course... silly. Then why not trigger a function on both `mouseenter` and `click` and set a flag to be able to tell.

Comment: "Click" event is registered when **both** mousedown and mouseup are originated from the same targetElement. So your question seems more like any [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `mouseenter` event fires when the mouse enters the control. The click event fires when the mouse is clicked. They are two separate events which call two separate event handlers. If you click just as the mouse enters the element they will be called within a short timespan of one another but they are still two distinct events.

It is also important that you differentiate between the `mouseenter` and the `mouseover` events. `mouseenter` fires when the mouse physically enters an element, whereas `mouseover` fires continually while the mouse remains over an element.

While you cannot trigger the click event per se, you can call the same function that is called by the click event handler. For example if you have this:

```
var myfunc = function (e) { ... }
document.getElementById("id").onclick = myfunc;
```

Then you could simply call `myfunc` directly and you would get the same result as if the mouse was clicked.

Answer (score 5):

They can 100% exist together, and this is a great question with no good answer... When you're on a mobile device, a mouseenter event will be thrown on tap... If you are also detecting onclick as well as mouseenter, then there will be a discrepancy between mobile devices and desktop machines.

It's kind of hard to solve such a small issue at the moment.

```
const x = document.getElementById('some_node')
x.onclick=(e)=>{
  e.stopPropagation()
  // this logic will be triggered on click for both desktop and mobile
}
x.onmouseenter=(e)=>{
  e.stopPropagation()
  // this logic will be triggered on click for mobile only (but will
  //have already been triggered on desktop when cursor entered node)
}
```

The only workaround I came up for this, and I think it's pretty clever, is using a eventlistener for taps/touches. The order/priority that these events are fired goes: touch > mouseenter > click.

Since the touch event is fired first, you can add a touch event listener (which will only register on a mobile device), and change a variable that prevents the mouseenter event from being triggered (which is the logic that would generally be conflicting with the onclick logic)... like this:

```
let isMobile = false
x.addEventListener('touchstart',(e)=>{
  isMobile = true
}, false);
```

Then your mouseenter would need to look like this:

```
x.onmouseenter=(e)=>{
  e.stopPropagation()
  if(!isMobile){
    // this logic will no longer cause a conflict between desktop and mobile
  }
}
```

Comment: They can be triggered with the same action on different devices but not simultaneously so a better check would be  by using an or instead of and => 
if ((evt.type === 'mouseenter') || (evt.type === 'click'))

Comment: @Osama_Almaani On a mobile device they can essentially be triggered simultaneously, as you don't have a cursor on a smartphone. The moment you tap the screen on a mobile device, it can/will fire a mouseenter and a click at basically the moment. The mouseenter event actually fires a fraction of a second before the click event is fired. (I'm talking about two independent event listeners targeting the same node).The difference in timing between each event firing is so small, that there will almost always be interaction between the two eventlisteners. Setting a timeout between logic is a solution.

Comment: @Osama_Almaani Or a more robust solution would be to add a touch event listener, to detect the tap on mobile right before the mouseenter is triggered, and using that to prevent the logic in mouseenter from being executed. (I added an example to my post)

Answer (score 0):

they can exist on the same object, think a button with a hover state and then a click action. The click event, though will only read the click event since the enter event actually occurred earlier.

You can create a var like `mouseIsOver`and set it to true when the enter event fires. I can be safely assumed, though that if a click happens the mouse is over the same target.

Answer (score 0):

The two events may happen at the same time, but they will still be processed on after the other. So the `if` you posted will never evaluate to `true`.

If you look at your code again you can see that it doesn't make sense. How can something be X and Y at the same time? It can't.

Comment: Thanks Jan, out of curiousity I have tried separating and evaluating them but it seems the click event would never be triggered:     if ((evt.type === 'mouseenter') {

//mouseenter event is true

}

if ((evt.type === 'click') {

//click event is true
}

Answer (score 0):

for the first question i think u got an answer....

however, for *Also how can I trigger the click event during the mouseenter event?*

u can use `trigger()` function..

http://jsfiddle.net/PDhBW/2/

if u want to read more about `trigger`
here is the link

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Thanks but I want my user to to still click on the link not trigger the click event while still hovering it..

Comment: confused.. but for that, why don't u use only `click()` ??  since `mouseenter` will always be called before the `click`event??   is there something u need to do in mousehover too ??

Comment: sorry for the confusion, but I have this issue that when I mouseover the image link, it will show the hover (triggered by mouseenter event). But when I click on it (hover is still shown), it won't trigger the click event. I try adding the trigger code as shown in the fiddle but when I mouse over , it will immediately trigger the click event. I need the mouseenter event to show the hover..

Comment: yes.. since whn `mouseenter` `click` is triggered.check this fiddle(console)... http://jsfiddle.net/PDhBW/3/ a simple.. call  to both these function is working..can u create a fiddle of your case??

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery event delegation, You can use binding multiple events at once

```js
$('#IdElement').on('mouseenter click', function () {
    //Your Code
});
```

http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events